# How to slide down after clicking link?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the webpage that I'm working on.

http://www.solved.com
What I want is when I click on the "state" Ex: CA I want the page to be slid down and show the results. Now it shows up the results but it doesn't slide down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change state links

```
<a href="#" id="AK">AK</a>
<a href="#" id="AL">AL</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#can_map" id="AK">AK</a>
<a href="#can_map" id="AL">AL</a>
```

And if you don't like the immediate scroll take a glance at https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll or other smooth scroll plugins.

Comment: This is a solution that I just found out too. Actually I did it with #repinfo_container.

Answer (score 1):

Use `a name` (or `id`) and hash tags (see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp for names)

For instance, have california's link be

```
<a href="#california">(image)</a>
```

and the section have

```
<a name="california">California</a>
```

(or preferably)

```
<a id="california">California</a>
```

*(Edit: that's the easy way to do it using just built-in browser capability. If you want to use jquery for a smooth slide, it looks like [this may be a good script](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/better-html-anchor-a-jquery-script-to-slide-the-scrollbar/) to investigate)*

Comment: Using name is so 2000! Use id instead.

Comment: Ah - that works too. Shows when the last time I did real HTML development was :p

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a nice effect of smooth scrolling to it like so:
Add a class to your link:

```
<a href="#can_map" class="anchor_class">Click me</a>
```

Then with jquery you can add the following on click event handler:

```
$('.anchor_class').click(function(){ 
    href = $(this).attr("href");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(href).offset().top};
    return false;
});
```